# More than one font with Cufon?

Tags: html, cufon

Is it possible to have more than one Cufon font on a website? If so, how?

Comment: In terms of web font technology cufon really is ancient history. Maybe try http://typekit.com/ instead?

Comment: I thought that Cufon was pretty up to date to use. Ok, is it possible with typekit then?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible. Link multiple font files to page. And Invoke Cufon.replace with fontFamily attribute. Example:

```
Cufon.replace('div.contactus-slogan', {
    fontFamily: "Myriad Pro"
});


Cufon.replace('div.slogan-left-content h1',  {
    fontFamily: "Myriad Pro Light"
});
```